# Needing a formula to find what % to subtract from X to find a number that's 30% away from X

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In my business we often sell items to Consumer A for $X.
But sometimes we sell items to Consumer B... who then turns and sells to Consumer A after marking it up 30%.

Consumer A always pays the same amount of money no matter who they buy it from.

I need to find out what I need to subtract from X to sell to Consumer B so that they can add 30% and get back to X.

What does the formula look like?

Thanks,

-Nathan

Answer (score 1):

You need to solve: $1.3(X-a)=X$, simplifying, you get: $a=\frac{.3X}{1.3}$

Answer (score 1):

You have to know how B applies the markup.  Do they add $30\%$ to what you charge?  In that case, you divide your price by $130\%=1.3$  In retail, $30\%$ markup means that $B$ bought it from you for $70\%$ of what they sold it for.  In that case, you charge them $70\%$ of your usual price.  As $\frac 1{1.3}\approx 76.9\%$, the two approaches give different reductions.